# Submit form button

Tags: html, css, button, contact-form

I tried making a custom submit button for my simple contact form because I wanted to style it a bit with CSS. I set the input type to submit and whenever I click the button it neither submits nor is click able.

I created a class called blue button, and my style will show but cannot submit.

```
 <a class="blue button" input type="submit">Everything? Send!</a>
```

I then tried this method instead and it submits, but it does not show my style that created!

```
 <input class="blue button" type="submit" value="Send">
```

Form

```
<form method="post" id="submitform" action="submitemail.php" >
    <input type="text" 
                            class="formstyle"
                            title="Name" 
                            data-placeholder="Name..." 
                            name="name" />

                            <input type="text"
                            class="formstyle" 
                            title="Email" 
                            data-placeholder="Website..." 
                            name="website" />

                             <input type="text" 
                             class="formstyle"
                             title="Email" 
                             data-placeholder="Email..." 
                             name="email" />

                              <input type="text"
                               class="formstyle" 
                               title="Email"
                               data-placeholder="Business or Personal?"
                               name="type" />

                            <textarea name="message" 
                            data-placeholder="Message..."
                            title="Message"></textarea>
```

Is there anyway to have a submit button from  element styled button like below?

```
<a class="blue button" input type="submit">Everything? Send!</a>
```

CSS as requested:

```
.button.blue {
    border: 1px solid #005998;
}

.button.blue .text {
    padding: 16px 31px 14px;
    text-transform: none;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #022268;
}

.button.blue .normal {
    background: linear-gradient(#00a7f7, #0563bb);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#00a7f7, #0563bb);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#00a7f7, #0563bb);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#00a7f7, #0563bb);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#00a7f7, #0563bb);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#00a7f7, #0563bb);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #12dbff inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #12dbff inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #12dbff inset;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #12dbff inset;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #12dbff inset;
    behavior: url(pie.htc);
}

.button.blue .hover {
    display: none;
    background: linear-gradient(#008af3, #0244a2);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#008af3, #0244a2);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#008af3, #0244a2);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#008af3, #0244a2);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#008af3, #0244a2);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#008af3, #0244a2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #12c4ff inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #12c4ff inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #12c4ff inset;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #12c4ff inset;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #12c4ff inset;
    behavior: url(pie.htc);
}
```

Comment: mind if u show us the css?

Comment: Man, you completely changed the question 3 times, ur making me lose my mind

Comment: @Ark I just added the CSS in the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a class="blue button" input type="submit">Everything? Send!</a>
```

This is totaly wrong. For form submit button:

```
<input type="submit" class="blue-button" value="submit" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you really understand the concept of css, either way here is what you can try:

1 - remove the .normal from the rules, its not used.

2 - put the input submit inside the form.

3 - order the class on css, like .blue.button not button.blue(jsut to organize)

4 - the .hover is a class or the effect? if its the effect the correct is :hover

try these

Comment: Hi, Thanks Ark! I understand CSS perfectly and .hover is the class. Thank you and I will try these!

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like;

```
<a class="blue_button" input type="submit"><input class="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send"></a>
```

and you may give `submit_button` a styling of `display: block; width: 100%; height: 100px; margin: none; border: none;`. I recommend giving it a width and height in `px` (fixed width). This is not tested.

Leaving space in defining class names to elements will treat them as multiple classes. For example, if you use `class="blue button"`, it says that the element may get styling defined on `.blue` and `.button`.

Comment: why use width: 100% with display block? block is already using the entire space if not declared